# Modify array elements on the fly [bash]

Tags: arrays, bash

If I have an array in bash such as:

```
a=(1 2 3)
```

Is there a way that I can print the array in a clean and concise manner BUT at the same time altering the output for each element (adding/removing text to it). Say I want to print the array but add "lol" to the end of each element when it is printed...E.g.

```
echo ${a[@]lol}
1lol 2lol 3lol
```

Does anyone know of a method to do this without having to create a new array or do some loop through the original array?

Comment: The question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20366609/258523) mentions the mechanism for this.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter expansion is applied to each element:

```
$ a=(1 2 3)
$ echo "${a[@]/%/lol}"
1lol 2lol 3lol
```

For printing specifically, consider using `printf`, which repeats the pattern until the arguments are exhausted:

```
$ printf "%slol\n" "${a[@]}"
1lol
2lol
3lol
```