# Passing more than one argument through to a command in a shell wrapper

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a custom command to copy files into a specific directory.
I am not sure the best way to do this.  Right now, the script is this

```
#!/bin/sh
cp -rf $1 /support/save/
```

I called this command `filesave`, it works great for 1 file, but if you do *.sh or something similar it only copies the first file.  This makes sense as that is the point of $1.  Is there an input variable that will just collect all inputs not just the specific one?

Comment: Have you tried `man sh`?  The documentation relevant to this particular question is usually fairly clear.

Comment: I am looking, but its not super helpful to me at the moment.  I am new to scripting.

Comment: BTW, `cp -rf $1 /support/save` won't work with filenames with spaces either. Even working with just one argument, this needs to be `cp -rf "$1" /support/save` to avoid string-splitting and glob expansion. http://shellcheck.net/ will catch that kind of error; also, if you can use bash rather than POSIX sh, see the bash tag wiki here on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for some pointers to good beginner docs. (Actually, many of those docs are useful even to folks targeting baseline POSIX sh; the Wooledge wiki, for instance, points out when it's using extensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
cp -rf -- "$@" /support/save
```

Use `"$@"` to expand to your entire argument list. It is **essential** that this be placed in double-quotes, or else it will behave identically to `$*` (which is to say, incorrectly).

The `--` is a widely implemented extension which ensures that all following arguments are treated as literal arguments rather than parsed as options, thus making filenames starting with `-` safe.

---

To demonstrate the difference, name the following script `quotdemo`.

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '$@: '; printf '<%s>\n' "$@"
printf '$*: '; printf '[%s]\n' $*
```

...and try running:

```
touch foo.txt bar.txt "file with spaces.txt" # create some matching files
quotdemo *.txt    # ...then test this...
quotdome "*.txt"  # ...and this too!
```

Comment: Thanks Charles,  I can use bash, how would you do it with bash?

Comment: The same way, for this simple a case; none of bash's extensions really matter much here.

Comment: So i am making another command with the opposite to cp a list of files from /support/save to your current directory.  i have the command as cp -rf -- /support/save/"$@" .  I am getting no such file or directory when i try and use it.

Comment: `/support/save/"$@"` only prepends the path to the first name in the array.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366609/prefix-and-postfix-elements-of-a-bash-array for details.